# Why a @Pointcut name method can't be overloaded?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

For Spring Framework 6.0.11 about AOP, having

```
public class CienciaPointcut {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.CienciaService.find*(..))")
    public void cienciaServiceFinds() {

    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.CienciaService.find*(..)) " +
              "&& target(cienciaService) && this(proxy)")
    public void cienciaServiceFinds(CienciaService cienciaService, Object proxy) {

    }

}
```

Observe that the `cienciaServiceFinds` method is overloaded and the latter used as:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="com.manuel.jordan.aop.pointcut.CienciaPointcut.cienciaServiceFinds(cienciaService, proxy)", 
               throwing="exception")
```

When the app/test is executed it fails at startup with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required parameter names not available when parsing pointcut cienciaServiceFinds in type com.manuel.jordan.aop.pointcut.CienciaPointcut
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.getDeclaredPointcuts(Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.java:299)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredPointcuts(ReferenceType.java:890)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$PointcutGetter.get(ResolvedType.java:261)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$PointcutGetter.get(ResolvedType.java:258)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4$1.hasNext(Iterators.java:213)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4.hasNext(Iterators.java:230)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.findPointcut(ResolvedType.java:767)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ReferencePointcut.resolveBindings(ReferencePointcut.java:148)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.resolve(Pointcut.java:189)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:331)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:312)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:222)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.obtainPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:226)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:288)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:320)
```

But when is used

```
public class CienciaPointcut {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.CienciaService.find*(..))")
    public void cienciaServiceFinds() {

    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.CienciaService.find*(..)) " +
              "&& target(cienciaService) && this(proxy)")
    public void cienciaServiceFinds2P(CienciaService cienciaService, Object proxy) {

    }

}
```

Observe that now is used `cienciaServiceFinds` and `cienciaServiceFinds2P`. And of course, used as:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="com.manuel.jordan.aop.pointcut.CienciaPointcut.cienciaServiceFinds2P(cienciaService, proxy)", 
               throwing="exception")
```

When the app/test is executed it works fine.

**Question**

- Why a `@Pointcut` named method can't be overloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works when the order of pointcut declaration is modified.

```
public class CienciaPointcut {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.CienciaService.find*(..)) " +
              "&& target(cienciaService) && this(proxy)")
    public void cienciaServiceFinds(CienciaService cienciaService, Object proxy) {

    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.CienciaService.find*(..))")
    public void cienciaServiceFinds() {

    }

}
```

Not an answer , but my assumption is that , when the AspectJ ecountered the `Advice` to process , the first pointcut name that match didn't satisfy the argument expectation.

The point here to note is , this is not about method overloading , rather the order of pointcut processing.

Attempted with Spring-boot-version : 2.6.4

**Update**

On debug , the issue is within the method `tryToDiscoverParameterNames()` called from
`Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.getDeclaredPointcuts()`
where the logic 'tries' to discover the parameters.

`pnames = tryToDiscoverParameterNames(pcs[i]);`

The method `tryToDiscoverParameterNames()` only compares the method names to get the parameter names through `Java15AnnotationFinder.getParameterNames()`. This results in incorrect identification of the pointcut method and the downstream logic fails to identify the parameters associated with the pointcut.

My read is that , this logic is faulty here and the condition check should also consider the arguments part of the pointcut to prevent this exception.

Comment: Logged a bug for this issue : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=582496

Comment: It is a bug, interesting the case. Thanks for the report!

Comment: It it not a bug, but was never implemented. If it works, then by pure chance.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, simple answer: It was never implemented, because it is nice to have at best and might lead to confusion at worst. See also [this mailing list thread from 2005](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/aspectj-dev/msg01383.html) and resulting [Bugzilla issue #88620](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=88620) which never has been implemented.

Ranjit, if you create bugs, then please on GitHub, no longer in the old Bugzilla instance. Thank you.

Comment: Sure Alex , will do that going forward. Thanks for the pointers